# AbortController polyfill

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, polyfills

Tried to make a polyfill for the abortController, but I ran into this error: [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AucZx.png)

```
Error: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Failed to read the 'signal' property from 'RequestInit': Failed to convert value to 'AbortSignal'.
```

```
class AbortSignalPolyfill extends EventTarget {
  readonly aborted: boolean = false
  onabort() {}
  addEventListener() {}
  removeEventListener() {}
}

class AbortControllerPolyfill {
  readonly signal = new AbortSignalPolyfill()
  abort() {}
}

;(function () {
  if (
    typeof window.Request === 'function' &&
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(window.Request, 'signal') &&
    window.AbortController
  ) {
    return
  }

  Object.defineProperty(window, 'AbortController', {
    writable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    value: AbortControllerPolyfill,
  })

  Object.defineProperty(window, 'AbortSignal', {
    writable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    value: AbortSignalPolyfill,
  })
})()
```

Can anyone tell me why?
Maybe the problem is in the abortControllerPolyfill and abortSignalPolyfill.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see no error message in the question.

Comment: sorry, added image by link

Comment: Just post the error text into the question. We can not copy and paste text from an image. And people can not search for text in an image in the future if they run into same type of problems.

Comment: ok, thanks, it's my first time :)